# Finding matches in a linked list in a queue-like way

Tags: c++, file, search, linked-list, queue

The task I was given was to read contents of a file into a linked list, then search for matches in a queue-like way and then output them in another file, while deleting matching entries both from LL and input file. Size of the input file tested on can be up to 60k entries.

Our input file contains fields as follows:
Time(an int value from 1 to the size of int)

Action(a char "A"(ask) or "B"(bid))

PK(a long long int, always 11 digits)

Name(string, max length 50)

An example of what input file might look is(without header):

```
Time Action      PK      Name
10     A    01010213061  Cat
73     B    03020114262  Dog
117    A    62734524312  Cat
123    B    67823216122  Zebra
167    A    12062342073  Dog
256    B    04342819213  Wolf
1023   B    02428912395  Cat
```

What my program should do is:

Find a matching name and not-matching action(first entry and last entry in the list), and put the following lines in the output file:

Time of last entry PKofA PKofB

Example(first entry and last):

```
1023 01010213061  02428912395
```

---

I must find matches in a queue like way, where the first entry output in a file would be "Dog" rather than "Cat", because Time between them is less so than between both entries of "Cat", while keeping in mind that we start with the top of the list to look for matches since they are the earliest.

My idea of resolving this issue was to look through the list once and find all matches, then subtract both times and calculate which match has the least value of time between them and output that first(putting priority on entries which comes first in case time-subtraction values are the same)

But issue is that if there are 60k+ entries in input file it will be awfully slow since I will have to search through list twice, once to find matches and evaluating time to determine which comes first, then again to find the nodes to delete from the linked list.

I tend to needlessly complicate things, but is there perhaps an easier, much quicker way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Can you make use of additional data structures, such as maps?

Comment: I believe that it is allowed, but I actually just a bit ago found a fitting solution. Rather than going down the list and comparing an element to the one one following it, I can just compare it to ones which comes before it, that way accomplishing the same goal.